# ClistView - Parent and Child on single view

Tags: yii

I have two table: 'Streams' and 'Punches'. One stream have many punches.
[image]

In my view, I use 'CListView' to show all punch's image of a stream. 
[image]

But I want show the stream's image in first page, and all punch's image will show on next pages. 
How can I do that? thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I resolved this problem... Instend of using CActiveDataProvider, I use CSqlDataProvider to "union" two table.

```
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_user')->queryScalar();
$sql='SELECT * FROM streams union SELECT * FROM punches';
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
// $dataProvider->getData() will return a list of arrays.
```